# Group tuples such that each item in a group shares no common elements with other members

Tags: algorithm, sorting, tuples, grouping

So I've run into a real world problem that goes like this: we have a list of pairs that we need to sort into groups. We want to minimize the number of groups that we have total, with the constraint that any member of a group cannot share an element with any other member of the group.

Here is an example. Our list of tuples is (A, B), (B, C), (C, A), (D, E), (F, G). We can form three groups by doing [(A, B), (D, E), (F, G)], [(B, C)], [(C, A)].

Is it possible to optimally solve this problem in polynomial time? How bad is the greedy solution? It is possible this has been posed as a different problem, but I can't quite figure out how to reduce it to something else (graph coloring comes to mind).

Comment: Could you post a longer example, or give an idea of the size of the real input? Can there be duplicate tuples? Do you expect every element to appear a more or less equal number of times?

Comment: The size of the input is somewhere in the range 20-60 (pairs). There are no duplicate tuples i.e. if (A, B) is in the set, there are no other (A, B) or (B, A). I don't have any distributional knowledge of the individual elements (though in practice I suspect some elements appear more often than others, I do not know this to be the case for the sake of the problem -- if some probabilistic knowledge of the problem yields a better average case solution, let me know and I can try to provide it)

Comment: Roughly how many distinct letters (or whatever those represent) does the input have? ​ Have you tried [approximating the minimum-vertex-cover-size](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_cover#Approximate_evaluation) of your graphs and their [complement graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_graph)? ​ Have you tried [approximating the treewidth](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.29.7198&rep=rep1&type=pdf) of your graphs? ​ ​ ​ ​

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem as stated can be thought of as the [edge-coloring problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edge_coloring#Algorithms): you have a graph where each tuple entry is a node and the edges are given by the tuples. Clustering the tuples into groups then corresponds to finding groups of edges that don't share endpoints (matchings), which can then be assigned the same color in an edge coloring. In other words, each edge coloring gives you a clustering and each clustering gives you an edge coloring. Unfortunately, it's **NP**-hard to find the best edge coloring, so your problem is in general **NP**-hard. There are approximation algorithms for this problem that produce constant-factor approximations, but unless **P**=**NP** there's no exact algorithm.

If you generalize this problem to allow any number of elements per tuple, then this problem gets a lot harder. The general version of this problem is indeed **NP**-hard, and really hard to approximate, by a reduction from graph coloring. I'll show an example of the reduction in a specific case, but it generalizes quite nicely.

Given a graph like this one:

```
 A -- B -- C
 |    |    |
 D -- E -- F
```

We'll create a set of tuples, one for each node, where each entry in the tuple is the set of edges adjacent to that node. For example, in the above graph, we'd form these tuples:

```
( AB, AD )
( AB, BC, BE )
( CB, CF )
( AD, DE )
( BE, DE, EF )
( CF, EF)
```

Now, imagine that two of these tuples don't overlap. This means that the two nodes corresponding to those tuples must not be adjacent, since if they were, the edge between them would be a common element in the tuples and therefore they couldn't be clustered. On the other hand, if two nodes aren't adjacent, then their tuples can be grouped together in the same cluster, since no edge in one tuple will be present in the other.

Given this setup, any coloring of the original graph gives a way of clustering the tuples (put all tuples for nodes given the same color into the same set; none of them are adjacent, so they don't conflict), and any way of clustering the tuples gives a coloring (color all nodes corresponding to each tuple in a cluster the same color). Therefore, finding the minimum number of clusters corresponds to finding the chromatic number of the original graph, which is **NP**-hard and not known to admit any approximation algorithms that get anywhere close to the true value.

Comment: I see a potential problem here.  The tuples seem to be actually restricted to pairs (the OP uses the word "pair" before "tuple" -- admittedly ambiguous), so I don't think you can encode the *set* of incident edges of a node into a *single* tuple in such a way that 2 tuples overlap iff their corresponding nodes share an edge.  I think you can encode this set using *multiple* tuples, but then it's not obvious (to me at least) how to go from a cluster of tuples to a colouring, since the tuples corresponding to a vertex might be distributed across several clusters.

Comment: @j_random_hacker I noticed that as well... after I'd written this up. :-) The edit to mention edge coloring up at the top should more accurately address this fact and still establishes NP-hardness.

Comment: Sorry about that guys. I should have realized that and restricted it to one or the other. In practice, this problem is just looking at pairs of elements.

Comment: @templatetypedef: Thanks for the update.  Since it turns out that edge colouring is already NP-hard, you don't need to bother with proving that the more general problem (arbitrary tuples instead of only pairs) is also NP-hard -- it must be, since it contains the pairs problem as a special case.

Comment: @j_random_hacker That's absolutely true. I included the more general version here just in case the problem *does* generalize to tuples... and because I think it's kind of a cool proof. :-)